# I want to store tabular data in c#.net

Tags: c#

I am having a requirement in asp.net in which i have to store tabular data.the table created in html has headings. and below that i have to design corresponding textboxes to store data in a sqlserver table after clicking a submit button below the table.how to design and code the table with c#.net?

Comment: So what is your problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite general and not specific to a problem. Have a look at [Data Grid control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx), this will fit your requirement.

Comment: datagrid control only displays data ,but i want a table with textboxes and dropdownboxes to be dynamically generated